# How to check if pkill was successful - better than my script?

Tags: command-line, process

Note: This question applies in general to Linux and also to the current version of Ubuntu (not just old unsupported versions as some have commented)

We use pkill to check if a program is running to kill it before restarting it when new code is being deployed.

```
pkill --signal 15 --pidfile programname.pid
```

This normally works, but when there is a problem and the application program hangs, signal 15 doesn't kill the process. The exit codes for pkill are:

```
EXIT STATUS
       0      One or more processes matched the criteria. For pkill and pidwait, one or more processes must  also  have  been  successfully signalled or waited for.
       1      No processes matched or none of them could be signalled.
       2      Syntax error in the command line.
       3      Fatal error: out of memory etc.
```

For obvious reasons to me, after thinking about it, it cannot return a code to indicate that the process kill was successful, since pkill only sends a signal to it and nothing more.  So I will have to check if the process was ended and if not try again with signal 9 and if not killed yet, try with signal 6 (or some others even).

So I guess doing some kind of if/elif/else/fi to test for this should suffice:

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill --signal 15 --pidfile programname.pid
result1=$?
echo 'result1 is ' $result1
if [ "$result1" -eq 0 ]  
then
    echo "programname found running"
    pgrep --pidfile programname.pid
    result2=$?
    if [ "$result2" -eq 1 ]
    then
        # happens if pid# is not found
        echo "programname killed successfully with signal 15"
        # restart the program that was killed
    else
        pkill --signal 9 --pidfile programname.pid
        result3=$?
        if [ "result3" -eq 0 ]
        then
            pgrep --pidfile programname.pid
            result4=$?
            if [ "result4" -eq 1 ]
            then
                echo "programname killed successfully with signal 9"
                # restart the pgram that was killed
            fi
        fi
    fi
elif [ $result1 -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "programname pid# not found. Is the system running?"
else
    echo "pkill exited with error" $result1
fi

echo 'Continue...'
```

This all seems a bit convoluted, or am I just being pedantic?  Is there a better way to achieve this result in a script?

Comment: we don't accept questions about 14.04.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Kill with signal 0 should show if a process is still running.

Comment: Since this is a question about bash scripting in general, I have removed the offensive version ref from the post...  I think, try to focus in the issue, not on the irrelevant "problem"

Comment: @Marco, would this differ significantly from using pgrep to determine if the process is still running?

Comment: @LifeBoy if you have the id anyway, you can use the `kill` command which reduces dependencies, because `kill` is part of bash. Otherwise there is no difference.

Comment: @muru, why did you remove the bash and pkill tags?  Surely they are relevant?  If I were looking for a solution in such a scenario, having these tags would be really helpful?  Maybe you can explain the reasons, so I can understand this better please.

Comment: @LifeBoy you're using bash, yes, but I don't see anything bash-specific here. The script is pretty much standard shell, you could have run it using dash or ksh without making any difference. People over use the bash tag here when all they want is a command-line solution without caring for bashisms. As for pkill, I didn't see any reason for this command to have its own tag - it's not hard to search for and it's _exactly_ the same command as pgrep (check it, they're the same binary).

Comment: @Rinzwind, the version is not relevant since my question applies to Linux shell scripting in general.  I have removed the reference, will you remove your comment please?

Comment: @LifeBoy yes it does. We only accept official NOT end of life Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @Rinzwind, can you point out to me where in the question any reference is made to end of life Ubuntu versions please?  I removed that reference since it doesn't matter, like I said.

Comment: @LifeBoy it was tagged 14.04 (and you remove that tag). and yes, I can see what was changed over time.

Comment: The *postscript* said rather clearly "*PS. I realise 14.04 is quite dated, but we need to run an oldish version of Ruby or Rails in this environment*" and changes stating "*This question applies in general to Linux*" mean SE *Unix & Linux* would be most appropriate, as initial wording & current edit still best suit that *sister* site on Stack Exchange - my 2c

Comment: @Rinzwind, I think this is a bit too pedantic.  I asked a perfectly legitimate question, one that would be of value to others in future.  I adjusted the question to be suitable here, yet my question is still -1.  Is the point of askubuntu to be useful or is being pedantic more important?

Comment: You got that wrong. AskUbuntu is for valid current/active Ubuntu version. No 14.04. No Mint.  If questions about 14.04 are accepted this site will become unmaintanable. This rule has a valid reason and needs to be adhered too. U+L is the site to go to for end of life Ubuntu.  And please stop using comments for other things than related to a question or answer. meta is for these kind of questions.  My stance is not mine...it is applied by all "editors" (as you can see from @quiverc comment on oct 25th).

Answer (score 0):

I decided that creating a function to do this is the better option.  Also, using a for loop seems to be a neater solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
trykill () {

    timeout=${2:-5} 
    # echo "wait =" $timeout

    # Run the loop for signal 15, 9 and 6
    for n in 15 9 6;
    do
        if [[ -f "$1.pid" ]]; then
            pkill --signal $n --pidfile $1.pid  
            result1=$?
        else
            result1=1
        fi
        #echo 'result1 is ' $result1
        if [ "$result1" -eq 0 ]  
        then
            echo $1 "found running, waiting" $timeout "seconds for process to die."
            sleep $timeout  # Wait # seconds set by second parameter
            pgrep --pidfile $1.pid
            result2=$?
            if [ "$result2" -eq 1 ]
            then
                 # happens if pid# is not found
                echo $1 "killed successfully with signal" $n"."
                return 0
            fi
        elif [ $result1 -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo $1".pid # not found." $1 "doesn't seem to be running. Starting it anyway."
            return 0
        else
            echo "pkill exited with error" $result1
            return 1
        fi
    done
}
```

And I call the function for each service I want to restart.  Here's a example script to do that.

```
#!/bin/bash
source trykill.sh

trykill $1
result1=$?
#echo 'result1 is ' $result1
if [ "$result1" -eq 0 ]  
then
    echo 'Start' $1 'again'
fi

echo 'Done.'
```

Comment: According to the manual, the exit code of `pkill` can not be used to tell if `pkill` killed the process successful. e.g exit 1 if no process can be found.

Comment: @Marco, that's why I check with pgrep to see if the process still exists after the pkill.  That way I know whether pkill was successful or not.